# BigQuery compare Date

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

In BigQuery table what I using some date stored in DateTime typed columns with value like "2016-01-20T00:00:00".
I want to run query that for example show row which included in some range (lets say from 2016-01-01 to 2016-02-28).

So problem is that when I put

`...Where data < TIMESTAMP('2017-01-30 00:00:00')...//less then`

it show me nothing but when I change it to opposite value like

`...Where data > TIMESTAMP('2017-01-30 00:00:00')...//greater then`

it returns me even those values that logically should be excluded (like 2017-01-20)

I have tested that TIMESTAMP('2017-01-20 00:00:00') returning '2017-01-26 00:00:00 UTC'.

So which method from bigQuery DateTime I should use to be able to compare dates that I have? May be I need to convert both of them into some kind 'milliseconds since' value?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this is interesting for you http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thank you all for help. Your answers and link has leaded me to solution.

```
where data<cast('2017-01-23 00:00:00' as datetime)
```

`cast('2017-01-23 00:00:00' as datetime)` provide `'2017-01-23T00:00:00'` value and bigQuery are happy with it and give me wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

If your column is of datetime int:

```
Where data < 20170130
```

and

```
Where data > 20170130
```

If your column is of datetime datatype, drop the TIMESTAMP:

```
Where data < '2017-01-30 00:00:00'
```

and

```
Where data > '2017-01-30 00:00:00'
```

Comment: better use an universal ISO format like '20170130' this is understood by any version and any regional settings

Comment: I tried it and got error "Argument type mismatch in function GREATER: 'date' is type int64, '2018-01-30 00:00:00' is type string". Also tried  '2018-01-30T00:00:00' with same error result. And just '20170130' give me same error. But when I don't use ' -mark then it retrun me everything, so it think it is some kind on "seconds since something" value.

Comment: @maximelian1986 I have updated the answer to include your datatype.

Comment: '00:00:00' is not necessary - at least that's what I see at the moment