# No matching signature for operator > for argument types: DATE, FLOAT64. Supported signature: ANY > ANY at [3:13]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to know the # of active members on some specific date.
So I code it like the one below but it is not working.

```
  expire_date, Date,
  CASE WHEN expire_date > 2022/10/30 AND Date < 2022/10/30 THEN 'active'
  ELSE 'inactive' END AS active FROM `F45_KR.EB_transaction_W4_Oct_2022_Clean`
```

How am I working this code to calculate the active members?
When I see the error message '<, =, >' are not working for the date style data
How do I have to do transfer and calculate the data range?

Moreover, How can I calculate the # of active members via above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery compare Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885214/bigquery-compare-date)

Comment: Yes it is It is for BQ data compare